Include fully qualified url within PHP code without using an ESI tag
Would like to call a fully qualified URL such as https://www.example.org/abc.html and include that HTML code snippet within a PHP page.
The reason for this is that the entire PHP page is dynamic but the HTML snippet would be cached by a CDN server.
Is this possible within PHP without using a ESI tag?
Thank you.

it's possible but makes ZERO sense. Either cache it on your own server and read from PHP or use client side include

With your setup it will be PHP execution time PLUS roundtrip to CDN. When you cache it on the local server, it's only php execution time
